# How SignlaR Generates Hub at run time

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

i need to know how SignalR Generates Hubs at run time , how he knows which class to generate to hub, and when it does it , is it on startup or it is on first or for each request.

i know that SignalR use different types of transports.
is there a specific hub proxy for each transport type also?

Answer (score 0):

The client creates a proxy for each hub. You invoke hub methods using these proxies. These proxies make sure that the messages sent to the server contain the name of the hub to create (you can find the description of the SignalR protocol [here](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/)). The server [parses](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/7dc8921376743b73856cb1f7bb9ca1db8de1abe2/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/HubDispatcher.cs#L152) the message and extracts the hub name and [creates](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/7dc8921376743b73856cb1f7bb9ca1db8de1abe2/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/HubDispatcher.cs#L180) a hub instance using [IHubActivator](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/1fba14fa3437e24c204dfaf8a18db3fce8acad3c/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/IHubActivator.cs) instance [registered](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/1fba14fa3437e24c204dfaf8a18db3fce8acad3c/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/DefaultDependencyResolver.cs#L91-L92) in the DI container.

Hub instances are transient and are created for each request and then discarded when the hub method invocation is complete.

Transport are independent on the hubs/proxies - they are means to move the data regardless of what the data actually is.

Comment: yes but when the server generate the js files , and how it does that?

Comment: If there is a GET request that ends with `/hubs` the server [generates](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/7dc8921376743b73856cb1f7bb9ca1db8de1abe2/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/HubDispatcher.cs#L280) proxies like [this](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/1fba14fa3437e24c204dfaf8a18db3fce8acad3c/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/DefaultJavaScriptProxyGenerator.cs)